# Are you supposed to add Newtonsoft to a WebAPI project or use the Newtonsoft that's baked into WebAPI?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

When I need to serialize/deserialize something manually am I supposed to use the Newtonsoft that's baked into WebAPI somehow or should I use the Newtonsoft form Nuget like normal?

For example, if I normally use Newtonsoft to do `JObject.Parse(json).GetValue("CatID").ToString();` should I be doing that with the Newtonsoft that comes with WebAPI somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Newtonsoft.JSON is a NuGet package which is probably used by the WebApi2 template by default.
When you say baked in, all that means is that WebApi2 already has that package added, just like you would add it to any other projects.

You won't be able to add it again, you might be able to upgrade it to the latest version, assuming other packages do not have a dependency on a specific version, which does happen sometimes.